How to access shared drive items with the new shared URL using OneDrive API?
I am encountering an issue with the OneDrive API and would appreciate any assistance or insights. I am trying to retrieve content from a shared link using the OneDrive API, but I keep getting the following error:
{"error":{"code":"unauthenticated","message":"The caller is not authenticated."}}

I used to successfully retrieve content with shared links from OneDrive in a format like this: https://1drv.ms/v/**s!AhcuJaxIdVk5gV86XGmv0X2a0P30?e=QYXv92**
Using the following API call: https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/{encoded_url}/root/content
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online
Problem: Now the format of the shared links have changed and are like this : https://1drv.ms/v/**c/16736b8f8892fe5e/EeWQ4oZ_sZtGmTFmsnFDU3oBM7cJoyL9tapTJU7gxZznzA**
I already tried encoding only the last part (EeWQ4oZ_sZtGmTFmsnFDU3oBM7cJoyL9tapTJU7gxZznzA) to Base64-url-safe and constructing the API URL as follows: https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!{encoded_url}/root/content
Extracted the relevant part of the link: EeWQ4oZ_sZtGmTFmsnFDU3oBM7cJoyL9tapTJU7gxZznzA
Encoded it to Base64-url-safe: RWVXUTRvWl9zWnRHbVRGbXNGRFUzb0JNOWNKb3lMOWthcFRKVTdneFp6bnpB
Constructed the API URL: https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!RWVXUTRvWl9zWnRHbVRGbXNGRFUzb0JNOWNKb3lMOWthcFRKVTdneFp6bnpB/root/content
However, this gets me this error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Bad Argument"
    }
}

Has there been any change in the OneDrive API regarding handling shared links that I might have missed? How can I get the content via API using the new shared link format?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
Best regards
